# Check if image exists

Tags: php, image, zend-framework

I want to check if the image is exist :

```
<?php
if(file_exists($this->baseUrl('upload/'.$this->lmObject->getLImage())) echo "EXIST";
else echo "NOT FOUND";
?>
<img src="<?php echo $this->baseUrl('upload/'.$this->lmObject->getLImage())?>" width="150" height="150" >
```

The output was : NOT FOUND while the image displayed well.. weird huh?. What I was wrong here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You seem to be passing a URL `file_exists`. This is not the correct way to use the function, and you should pass a filesystem path instead.

You need to use something like:

```
if(file_exists(APPLICATION_PATH.'upload/'.$this->lmObject->getLImage()))
```

Comment: +1 To clarify the [PHP HTTP Wrapper](http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.http.php) does not support `stat()` and that is why askers code will not work. See the [file_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) documentation for more information.